# Firefox / uBlock Origin only showing camera / image apps when clicking on a file upload button

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, firefox-for-android

I'm looking to import my uBlock Origin settings from my desktop PC, which is in a text file, to uBlock Origin in Firefox for Android.

The issue is: When I click on the 'Restore from file...' button on uBlock Origin in Firefox Android, I only get prompted to choose between camera / image apps:

[image: screenshot of issue described above]

In a Windows PC, clicking on that button will open up an Explorer window allowing you to select a text file to import. I can't import a text file with any of the above apps  shown. Is there an app I should install to allow this? How should I configure it?

Details: I have Google Drive and ES File Explorer installed. This is on Android 4.4.2, Firefox for Android 44.0, uBlock Origin 1.5.5.

Comment: Not sure if this help, but do you have Google Drive installed? Otherwise, I suspect this is a bug on uBlock Origin: it seems the file type (or [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type)) is set to `image/*` for unknown reason.

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes, I also have Google Drive installed.

Comment: @AndrewT. The file type is set to `text/plain`, see [source code](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/blob/89148351e86ce933ba5fc8cc998681a884c13a3f/src/settings.html#L51). I need to investigate why this happens.

Comment: @beeshyams Could you add that as an answer so I could accept it? That made it work for me. After I installed App Picker Classic, I could then select it as the file upload app and then choose another app that could upload the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [confirmed by OP](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/136679/firefox-ublock-origin-only-showing-camera-image-apps-when-clicking-on-a-file?noredirect=1#comment173582_136679) this app resolved the problem [App Picker Classic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.anyro.picker). From app description

> If you have app choices that are currently hidden - maybe you chose "Always" by accident once, but you'd like to be able to reinstate the app and choose each time - then reset these by clearing the defaults in the application manager of your phone/tablet.

In addition, this app permits working with some app intents and resolves common URLs. One needs to install the app, reset defaults and enable required app.

**Note**

Despite the app being not updated for last two years, it even works with Marshmallow, as can be seen from @Arlinds answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/133570/131553) - which was a surprise to me, and the reason for remembering it !

Comment: I'd like to add here that in my case, I didn't even have to clear the defaults through App Picker Classic. I just had to install it and then it was shown as a choice in the file upload app.