# Keep asking for apps on every action on Marshmallow

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, default-applications

In Lollipop, I was being asked for the app to be used for every action. For example, when I open a link, I was asked for the browser. When I have to select an image, I was asked about the app that would browse for images. This behavior is very convenient for me.

Now after upgrading to marshmallow, I get asked only once, and then that becomes the default. Meaning that if I do a mistake, I'm done. Now for the browser, I see the option for that in settings -> Default Apps. But for selecting images, I don't see that option. I selected ES file explorer for that and I'm stuck with that.

How can I change the default image selector app, or even better, how can I be always asked every time I do an action that requires anything that has multiple apps that can do it, just like it was on lollipop?

EDIT:
There's no option to use app only once. Check out the screenshot. 
[image]

Comment: Clear defaults for ES app/any app from app info and always use *JUST ONCE* while choosing an app.

Comment: @MANI thanks for the info about the reset. That is helpful. But there's no choice to use the app only once on my marshmallow, for some reason (check the screenshot). It was there on lollipop though...

Comment: @beeshyams Actually I already installes "better open with", but it doesn't show in the list of choosing stuff for the problem above. I'm trying choose to add an image in Google Keep.

Comment: Try [local storage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ianhanniballake.localstorage) app. It works well for me on Marshmallow

Comment: @beeshyams It doesn't install... it gives me error 505...

Comment: I don't know why. Try rebooting and installing. I can't help with that :(

Comment: @beeshyams Yeah, I know. It's incompatible with my device :( Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think it works same as JUST ONCE. It is missing ALWAYS option.

Comment: You can give this app a shot http://android.stackexchange.com/a/136725/131553